# Messing up with generics and graph modelling

Tags: c#, generics, inheritance, graph

I'm pretty new with C# and .NET. I'm trying to model a graph with heterogeneous data. I mean i would like to be able to do something like this:

```
// Simple graph modeling using generics
public class Node<T>
{
  private T data;
  public Node(T data)
  {
    this.data = data;
  }
}

public class Edge<T, U>
{
  private T source;
  private U destination;

  public Edge(T source, U destination)
  {
    this.source = source;
    this.destination = destination;
  }
}
```

Building it this way:

```
Node<Person> p = new Node<Person>(new Person("Red John"));
Node<Computer> c = new Node<Computer>(new Computer("MyComputer"));
graph.AddNode(p);
graph.AddNode(c);
graph.AddEdge(new Edge<Person, Computer>(p, c));
```

But of course the graph class definition won't let me do this:

```
public class Graph<T> where T : CommonBaseClass
```

I've also tried defining a base class for both person and computer, but of course it's not working. Any help/idea suggestion? I need heterogeneous data because i have to merge list of different nodes.

Thanks for helping!

Comment: Please post a compiling code example with all necessary code, especially including the definition of `Graph<T>`, `Person` and `Computer`.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In cases like this, it can be convenient to have your generic classes derive from non-generic classes.  That way, you can refer to all types of Nodes through a simple `Node` class:

```
public class Node 
{ 
    public Node(object data) 
    { 
        this.Data = obj;
    }

    public object Data { get; protected set; }
}

public class Node<T> : Node
{
    public Node(T data) : base(data) { }

    new public T Data 
    {
        get { return (T)base.Data; }
    }
}
```

If type `object` is too primitive, you can use generic constraints instead:

```
public class Node
{
    public Node(IGraphData data)
    {
        this.Data = obj;
    }

    public IGraphData Data { get; protected set; }
}

public class Node<T> : Node where T : IGraphData
{
    public Node(T data) : base(data) { }

    new public T Data
    {
        get { return (T)base.Data; }
    }
}

public class Edge
{
}

public class Edge<T, U> : Edge
    where T : Node where U : Node
{
    // ...
}
```

Now, your `Graph` class can allow any type of `Node` and `Edge`:

```
public class Graph
{
    public void AddNode(Node node) { /* ... */ }
    public void AddEdge(Edge edge) { /* ... */ }
}
```

Comment: +1, I have used this pattern many times before. Often you can also use an INode and IEdge instead of a concrete implementation

Comment: IGraphData definition doesn't exist, I don't see how your second example compiles.

Comment: I didn't elaborate; use `object` if your data doesn't have a type. `IGraphData` is a theoretical interface for the data held by the graph.

Answer (score 2):

You could use an interface (say IGraphItem) instead of a common base class, and have both Nodes and Edges implement IGraphItem.

Then Graph could be changed to:

```
public class Graph<T> where T : IGraphItem
```

Let me know if I've misunderstood the question, I'm not 100% sure this is what you were asking about...

Comment: I've used something very similar to this to solve a fairly similar issue.

Answer (score 1):

Yoy can do this by `interface`

```
public interface INode
{
    List<INode> Nodes { get; set; }
}

public class Person : INode
{
    public List<INode> Nodes { get; set; }

    private string _name;

    public Person(string name)
    {
        _name = name;
    }
}

public class Computer : INode
{
    public List<INode> Nodes { get; set; }

    private int _number;

    public Computer(int number)
    {
        _number = number;
    }
}
```

And use:

```
var person = new Person("P1");
var computer = new Computer(1);

person.Nodes.Add(computer);
computer.Nodes.Add(person);
```